# How to hide distractions in VSCode's Zen mode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There is the picture with current view of Zen mode.

[image: Zen mode in VSCode]

Some parts of this picture are distracting me.

- Minimap
- Scrollbar
- Strange line on the left side (resizing hook)

Is it possible to hide those things **only** for Zen mode?

I know, minimap can be hidden by using settings/hotkeys, but it hides minimap globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary workaround:

- Switch off minimap globaly
- Change colors for borders and scrollbar to the same as editor's background:

```json
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "scrollbarSlider.background": "#fafafa",
        "scrollbarSlider.activeBackground": "#fafafa",
        "scrollbarSlider.hoverBackground": "#fafafa",
        "editorGroup.border": "#fafafa"
    }
}
```

This is a bit ugly and it will to affect other scrollbars inside the editor. But this is better than the distracting things:

[image]

There is also [the issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/45617) related to this.